# Finding Points Within a Distance of a Latitude/Longitude - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am using [geolocator](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/geolocator): `^5.3.2+2` with `flutter 1.73.3`. I am creating publications with latitude and longitude.

```
Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
longitude = position.longitude;
latitude = position.latitude;
```

I would like to get all previous points given a meter so I'll get  all point in a radius area

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a points in distance you want by using Geohash.

It seems that there are many geohash package.

ex) https://pub.dev/packages/dart_geohash